# When i click on Media > library in WordPress admin images are not showing why is that?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes

I am using WordPress 4.8 in my website. When i click on Media > library i found following error "No Results Found
The page you requested could not be found. Try refining your search, or use the navigation above to locate the post."

Why my Media "upload.php" page is not opening?
http://www.classic-polos.com/wp-admin/upload.php

I have also attached Screenshot. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDNOb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Check with these options:

1 => Add this code in `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

2 => Assign 755 recursive permissions to wp-content folder

3 => upgrade your wordpress to the latest version

Thanks,

Comment: its already 755 and i am also using current WordPress, this did not work me